# Command that mentions a user upon join that says who they were invited by?

Tags: discord.js, bots

I've been looking around and can not work out how to make command that mentions a user upon join that says who they were invited by.

I've provided a picture with what I'm trying to do; if anyone could help that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to find who invited a specific person.

However there is a way to achieve this by caching the invites and checking which invite use increased when the new user joined. The invite creator will definitely be the inviter!

The Discord.js team provides a very good guide on this at https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites.md  :)